# Grid adapter not getting notified for data change

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I have a grid with images and a text item,The problem is that images load alright but only on scrolling. If I understand correctly `getView()` is called again when we scroll hence the view is updated.

Until the grid is scrolled the images are not loaded.

I think that is because the adapter is not being notified of image load properly. I am calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()` from the point where I update data. But nothing happens.

I have the following implementation for a grid adapter `gridView()`

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = null;
        RecordHolder holder = null;
        row = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.seriesTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(com.watch_free_tv.R.id.seriesNameAS);
            holder.seriesDisplayImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(com.watch_free_tv.R.id.seriesIconAS);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SeriesData seriesItem = data.get(position);
        holder.seriesTitle.setText(seriesItem.getSeriesTitle());
        String imageUrl = null;
        imageUrl = seriesItem.getImageURL();
        if(seriesDisplayImageMap.get(seriesItem.getSeriesID())==null)
        if((imageUrl != null&&(!imageUrl.isEmpty()))) {
            seriesDisplayImageMap.put(seriesItem.getSeriesID(), AsyncImageLoader.getInstance().loadDrawable(
                    imageUrl, imageLazyLoad,this));
        }

        if (imageUrl!=null&&(!imageUrl.isEmpty()))
            if(seriesDisplayImageMap.containsKey(seriesItem.getSeriesID())){
                holder.seriesDisplayImage.setImageDrawable(seriesDisplayImageMap.get(seriesItem.getSeriesID()));
                }

        return convertView;
    }
```

The `AsyncImageLoader` in above code calls up a method where I check in image cache for image or load the image and return to grid

Implementation of the `AsynchImageLoader.loadDrawable` method is:

```
public Drawable loadDrawable(final String imageUrl, final ImageCallback imageCallback, AllSeries_GridViewAdapter callingAdapter) {
        if (imageCache.containsKey(imageUrl)) {
            SoftReference<Drawable> softReference = imageCache.get(imageUrl);
            Drawable drawable = softReference.get();
            if (drawable != null) {
                callingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return drawable;
            }
        }
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                imageCallback.imageLoaded((Drawable) message.obj, imageUrl);
            }
        };
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Drawable drawable1 = loadImageFromUrl(imageUrl);
                imageCache.put(imageUrl, new SoftReference<Drawable>(drawable1));
                Message message = handler.obtainMessage(0, drawable1);
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }.start();

        return null;
    }
```

I am calling the `notifyDataSetChanged` before returning the image, this should be calling the `getView` again?

can somebody point what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer but you should look into using something like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).  I use one line of code to load the image in my adapter and don't have to worry about caching or calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: @user1199931 : That looks seriously neat.. I will try that out soon. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: I used Picasso in my application and it works great. ButI still would like to know whats going wrong in my code above.